# Updating a Textview with a Button click (both in a custom Dialog)

Tags: android, button, dialog, textview, onclicklistener

I want to create a custom keyboard inside a custom dialog.
It has a Textview on top and 12 buttons bellow (it's a numerical keyboard)
What I want is: when the buttons are pressed they update the Textview values.
I don't know the right place to put the "OnClickListener" and how to update the Textview...

Here is the keyboard layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valor"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnP"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="."/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ok"/>
</TableRow>
```

And here is the MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button teclado = (Button)findViewById(R.id.teclado);
        teclado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showCustomDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.teclado);
        dialog.show();

        final TextView valor = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.valor);

        Button btn7 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.teclado);
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                valor.setText("Test");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are'nt you using a editText with input type set to number?

Comment: Because I want to make an Expense Manager.
And I think that a special number keyboard is a good idea for the app. To let it more sophisticated, you know...

Comment: What is/isn't happening? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, the error is in the "Button btn7..." Something is wrong in that part of the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found this implementation strange.

I would suggest using DialogFragment, and you can encapsulate everything in there.
http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

You will be able to use the normal setOnClickListener in that fragment.

```
Button btn7 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn7); **"why R.id.teclado?"**
btn7.setOnClickListener(this)
```

And your fragment can implement OnClickListener with switch

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn7:
            valor.setText("asdf");
            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            ...
            break;
        ....
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I want to give some basic idea regarding this. you can modify this according to your requirement.

Give your layout an id. and use `layoutinflater` to inflate your xml in dialog.
 
If you want your xml layout in your dialog box you you can do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_id_here, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

Put above code in `Button`'s onclicklistener. And check Button's view through `Switch` case like `case 1: "this button id"` then insert this number in Text view.

 Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

R.id.teclado is not in the dialog layout

Change:
Button btn7 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.teclado);

To:
Button btn7 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn7);